# Identification of cells containing the gene of interest at a double strand break instead of undergoing recombination

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, homework, human-genetics

If I tried to knock in a gene for example KANMX and want to swap it with say some gene "x", but, since, there can be double strand break in the DNA and KANMX may get inserted within the ds break instead of undergoing homologous recombination with gene x, in that case how can we identify the colonies which can be a mixture of the following :-
A.) Undergoing proper recombination and now having KANMX but not gene x
B.) Having both gene X and KANMX (how can we specifically identify these?)
C.) Undergoing no homologous recombination (one way is using G418 sulphate).

This question was asked in my class, one possible reasoning given was that we can make forward primers upstream of gene x, which won't work for KANMX and only reverse primer will work.

But I was thinking how we will screen so many colonies and can we use probes instead of primers or even a simple thing as gel electrophoresis to see size differences?

I will be very thankful if anyone can clear up this doubt!

I was troubleshooting the question with designing probes upstream of gene x and also only specifically for kanmx to differentiate the two or even observing size differences through AGE.